# Android - align center the RelativeLayout in FrameLayout

Tags: java, android

`adView` is the AdMob's View and I am adding it to another frame view like this:

```
adView = new AdView(this);

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mFrameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
   AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   //important I use this to make it appear on the bottom
adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);


relativeLayout.addView(adView, adViewParams);
```

It appear on the bottom of the frame layout, hence on the bottom of the screen (the frame layout is my screen). But is in not in the center, it is left aligned. How to align center the `RelativeLayout` in `FrameLayout`.

EIDT: Here is the FrameLayout in case you need it:

```
    // FrameLayout
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams framelayout_params =
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    mFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(framelayout_params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this an it worked:

```
adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Please confirm if it is correct.

Comment: Consider using `RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` instead, since `RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT` also tries to align **both vertical** and horizontal, contradicting `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`.

Comment: Thank, changing according your comment @AndrewT. Could you please tell the second parameter meaning `RelativeLayout.TRUE`?

Comment: After researching a bit, I went to read the source code for `RelativeLayout`. Apparently, it's a trick to allow using `addRule()` with "boolean". The second parameter of `addRule()` accepts `int`, which supposed to be the ID of another `View` (compare when using XML). When the rule is not related to another `View` (like in this case), it uses 0 ("false") and -1 (`RelativeLayout.TRUE`), since both are otherwise invalid IDs for `View`. [Link to the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java)